# How to add edit items to the predefined lists in TFS Work Items

Tags: tfs

I am trying to follow [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/882b6c7a-a7ec-4401-99fc-61d04029e084#5b8c1b44-3121-4c47-a994-3dd3e1395472) article to do the same for adding a new State to a particular project's Bug work item. By default I can only see [image: this]. I wanted to add a new state, "On Hold"

But I perhaps followed it wrong and ended up getting [image: this]

The error says "Open Transition Active~On Hold to add at least one Reason." How do I open that transition and where do I add one reason. What is the reason it is talking about? I only want to add a new state.

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double click the `Active~On Hold` Transition , select the `Reasons` tab and type in at least one reason.

[image: Reasons]

After saving the .wit file, you must click `Refresh` from the Team Explorer menu in order to see changes.
[image: Team Explorer refresh TFS]

Comment: I did that but it is not showing against the State drop down..I still have only Active showing... have I connected it properly?

Comment: This applies for existing items. To move new items directly to `On Hold` you need to create another transition from the very first transition (the top left in your screenshot). Also don't forget to refresh TFS data after each modification.

Comment: How do I do that? I have a test project that I created on TFS for which I am the admin. When I tried to log a new bug it gave me just the default Active state. Then I did what you recommended and tried again by opening a new bug window. Still the only thing I saw was Active. I could not see On Hold in the drop down.

Comment: After you SAVE a work item in `Active` state, do you see the `On Hold` state?

Answer (score 0):

In the work item editor, double click on the Transition between your Active and On hold states.  Under 'Transition Detail' you should see 'From: Active' and 'To: On Hold'.  Change 'From: Active' to blank so it should show 'From: '.  Now save the editors, click 'refresh' from the Team Explorer menu and any new bugs you create will have 'On Hold' as an option for the state.