# Refresh TFS Process Template

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

I created a custom TFS process template with altered work items. After I uploaded the template to TFS and began testing the new process, I realized I had forgot some state transitions for one of the work items. I altered the XML to include the new transition states and uploaded the process template to TFS again. However, the new transition states are still not showing up in the state drop down list. Is there something else I need to do to refresh the work item or the process template so the new transition states appear in the state drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

You must refresh TFS data from Team Explorer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11121611/147211).